# How many digits of randomness does GUID provide?

Tags: random, guid, entropy

I know GUID is not random and that should not be used for security purposes, but how many random digits does it provide ? (To which extent can it be used as source of entropy for any task that does not require security)

Of 32 digits in example, maybe 4/5 are random?

Comment: Usually talks are about random bits in UUID. 122 or 121 bits of randomness out of 128 are provided

Answer (score 2):

A version 4 UUID (also known as GUID) contains 122 randomly chosen bits; the other 6 bits are fixed. (There are other versions of UUIDs; see RFC 4122.)  UUIDs are intended as identifiers, not as a source of randomness.